# Plausible Liveness Problem on Casper FFG

Tags: proof-of-stake

Recently, I read about "Casper The Friendly Finality Gadget", when facing with Theorem 2 (Plausible Liveness), I don't understand its corresponding proof. Basically, I have two questions:

1. how can we know there exists a descendant a' of a such that its height is h(b) + 1? I mean, what if at the time b has been voted, there are no checkpoints after a satifying h(a')=h(b) + 1 ? And when there is one, possibly there may have another target checkpoint whose height is even higher than b?
2. Does the source checkpoint of a supermajority link must be a justified checkpoint or not?

[image]